# How to override the ASP.NET MVC 3 default model binder to resolve dependencies (using ninject) during model creation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, model-binding

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that uses Ninject to resolve dependencies. All I've had to do so far is make the Global file inherit from `NinjectHttpApplication` and then override the `CreateKernel` method to map my dependency bindings. After that I am able to include interface dependencies in my MVC controller constructors and ninject is able to resolve them. All that is great. Now I would like to resolve dependencies in the model binder as well when it is creating an instance of my model, but I do not know how to do that.

I have a view model:

```
public class CustomViewModel
{
    public CustomViewModel(IMyRepository myRepository)
    {
        this.MyRepository = myRepository;
    }

    public IMyRepository MyRepository { get; set; }

    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I then have an action method that accepts the view model object:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(CustomViewModel customViewModel)
{
    // Would like to have dependency resolved view model object here.
}
```

How do I override the default model binder to include ninject and resolve dependencies?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but my opinion is that your view models should not have dependencies. This looks like the active record pattern, which sounds nice and clean, but really ends up being hard to maintain. Its ok for your controller to have dependencies, like a service or something. Your controller is going to either call customViewModel.Save() or this.myServiceDep.Save(customViewModel). The latter is going to pan out better.

Comment: You are likely correct, but I am still interested in the answer. I would like to know how to override the default model binder to perform such a task, even if I do not use it in production.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having view models depend on a repository is an anti-pattern. Don't do this.

If you still insist, [here's an example](http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/39/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-2---part-2--modelbinders-viewmodels) of how a model binder might look like. The idea is to have a custom model binder where you override the `CreateModel` method:

```
public class CustomViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;
    public CustomViewModelBinder(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
      ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        return _kernel.Get(modelType);
    }
}
```

which you could register for any view model you need to have this injection:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(CustomViewModel), 
  new CustomViewModelBinder(kernel));
```

Comment: I am realizing this is not good practice, but can you explain more about why that is the case? Is it only bad practice to have a view model depend on a repository or is the issue more broad in that it is bad practice to have a view model with any dependencies at all?

Comment: @Chevex, yes, the issue is with view models having a repository. This means that those view models will pull data from somewhere which is not what they are designed for. View models are just transport objects containing formatted data for a specific view. They are populated by a controller action which queries a repository or a service.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. Truth be told this was an off the cuff example specific to this question. So, in general, having a view model with a dependency is ok then?

Comment: @Chevex, no, view models shouldn't have dependencies. Simple POCOs. You might decorate them with formatting and validation attributes, but don't give them dependencies.

Comment: Oh okay, so there are two problems here. One is that my view model should not have access to a data source and the other is that my view model should not really have dependencies on other services/components at all. Makes sense. Thank you for the info.

Comment: Just reading this as I was thinking about doing the same thing. In my case, I want to include selection options in my ViewModel to be used with a drop down.  To populate the list of selections in the ViewModel, I could inject a IRepository to fetch the items.  How else would you achieve this?  Would you do it outside of the ViewModel?

Comment: I'll add my own opinion into this.  I disagree that ViewModels using injected Repository interfaces is an anti-pattern.  In fact, I think its EXACTLY what you want to do.  There are quite a few discussions on SO and elsewhere about keeping your controllers thin and dumb, and your models/viewmodels fat and smart.  I do agree that injection of repositories should be done via IoC and interfaces for the repositories (for easy testability), but dont agree its bad to have business logic/persistence code in your ViewModels.  I put forth that is exactly how you should do it in fact.

Comment: @Darin, is this an anti pattern if this is used to validate the viewmodel (for instance check that an email address is unique) ?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, what do you say about injecting a repository into a ViewModel just for populating the DropDownlists? Because populating the lists (like `ViewBag.countriesSelectList`) in `Create` action and then in the `HttpPost Create` action (on `ModelState.IsValid == false`) is duplication.

I have a field `Countries` in the ViewModel itself, that gets the list of countries from the repository. I know this is an anti-pattern, but I don't see any downside if I just use it to populate the dropdownlists.

Comment: If my viewmodel is IValidatableObject, is it still bad to inject a validator into the viewmodel constructor which I can use in the validate method?